# Where is DeviceCodeProvider?

Tags: uwp, microsoft-graph-api

I copied a small example of Microsoft Graph API usage (from a Microsoft page) into my application.

I added Microsoft.Graph and Microsoft.Graph.Core to my dependencies via the Nuget package manager. Still, the example won't compile. It doesn't recognize the class "DeviceCodeProvider" and can't offer any suggestions as to where to find it.

I think this class might be part of a package called Microsoft.Graph.Auth, but that package does not appear in Nuget.

Does anyone know which package this class belongs to and how I install it?

More generally, what is the right way to go about figuring out which package contains a class? I am always encountering code examples that refer to things without specifying where they are coming from, and find it tedious and inefficient to google around until I happen to spot the answer. Surely, there must be a more organized way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The example I'm referring to is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=CS

Comment: Please try installing `Microsoft.Graph.Auth` package in your project and let us know if it helps

Comment: I can't figure out how. When I type Microsoft.Graph.Auth into the Nuget search, it doesn't appear.

Comment: I should add that this is a UWP application, not .NET. Is Microsoft.Graph.Auth available in UWP?

Comment: It will show up when we click the checkbox **Include prerelease** in  NuGet package **browse** window

Comment: Thanks. I found it and installed it. Unfortunately, the compiler still can't find the symbol. I added 'using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;' to my source file, but the compiler flags this as an unknown package.

Comment: Hi Flarosa, please use `Microsoft.Identity.Client`  and the document which can help you in implementing MS Graph in UWP is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-uwp)

Comment: Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It was included in the `Microsoft.Graph.Auth` nuget package, but the package was deprecated.

[image: DeviceCodeProvider]

---

Current flows should use `DeviceCodeCredential`, which is included in the `Azure.Identity` package. Example:

Code:
[image]

Login in browser:
[image]

Final result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Device code flow isn't a great choice for a UWP app. That flow is really more for command-line apps where UI isn't always available. It requires you to open a browser, go to a URL, input the device code given, and authenticate/consent.

With UWP, you have UI available, so using code like Hari Krishna posted, or even using the Graph sign-in control included in the [Windows Community Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Graph.Controls) is a better choice. There's a tutorial for creating your first UWP Graph app that uses the toolkit here: https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/tutorials/uwp